# addClass and className does not work in js

Tags: javascript, css

`hr1` is the id of a line which dynamically created using JavaScript.  Then I tried to set the color of its `bottom border`.  When I run the code, I find that version 1 works but version2, version 3, version 4 and version 5 doesn't work.  Hope someone could help me point out why this happens. Thank you in advance.

Version 1:

```
$('#hr' + 1).css("border-bottom-color", "red");
```

version 2:

```
js:
$('#hr' + 1).addClass('thing');

css:
.thing {
    border-bottom-color: red;
}
```

version 3:

```
js:
$('#hr' + 1).className = "thing";

css:
.thing {
    border-bottom-color: red;
}
```

version 4:

```
js:
$('#hr' + 1).attr('class', "thing");

css:
.thing {
    border-bottom-color: red;
}
```

version 5:

```
js:
$('#hr' + 1).setAttribute('class', "thing");

css:
.thing {
    border-bottom-color: red;
}
```

Comment: version 3 doesn't work because you're adding a className property to a jQuery object, not the dom node itself. You would have to do `$("#id")[0].className = "thing"`

Comment: for version 2 add important to css `border-bottom-color: red; !important;` to `.thing` class

Comment: everything in js work in js, do not blame js :v

Comment: @GovindKumar Do you mean to put !important right after "border-bottom-color: red" in the ".thing"? I did it but it does not work for some reasons.

Comment: @hamohl You are absolutely right.  Thank you.

Comment: @hamohl I also tried to use "$('#hr' + 1).attr('class', "thing");" but it does not work as well.  Do you have any idea what could possibly be wrong?

Comment: No it should work, so check that your css file working at all, and that you are updating the right file.. :)

Comment: @hamohl you are right again. Sorry to bother you again, do you mind if you could point out what is wrong with version2 and 4?

Comment: I guess I know the reason.  hr1 is dynamically created so I don't have it in my html.  So DOM node does not work whereas JQuery object works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number 2 should work, so it's probably your CSS that doesn't apply (or .thing is overridden by some other css rule). Try to make your selector `.thing` more specific.

```css
.hr {
  height: 2px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}

.thing {
  border-bottom-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hr1" class="hr"></div>
<div id="hr2" class="hr"></div>
<div id="hr3" class="hr"></div>
<button onClick='$("#hr1").addClass("thing")'>Change color</button>
```

Comment: I don't think it is the reason.  I took the advice from Govind that I put !important; into the css but it still does not work.

Comment: @zxc34 Using too much !important can be cumbersome, if you are working with large project with dynamic contents.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. via creating a **hr** with id **testId** like

css

```
 .thing {
     border-bottom-color: red; }
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {   $("#testId").addClass("thing") });
```

Please see below link for working example.

https://jsfiddle.net/mohan_rathour/2h779793/3/[1](http://jsfiddle.net/mohan_rathour/2h779793/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout All The Version ...

```js
$("#hr1").css({"border-color": "red","border-width":"4px","border-style":"solid"});

$("#hr2").addClass("thing");

var elm = document.getElementById("hr3");
elm.className = "thing";
```

```css
.div1{
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
   background-color:cyan;
}
.thing{
  border-color:red;
  border-width:4px;
  border-style:solid;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Version 1 :
<div id="hr1" class="div1">
</div>

Version 2 :
<div id="hr2" class="div1">
</div>

Version 3 :
<div id="hr3" style="height:50px;width:50px;background-color:cyan;">
</div>
```

Comment: I wish I could give accept two answers.  Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

U are trying to run script before the element is rendered please used like this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#hr' + 1).css("border-bottom-color", "red");
    });
```